# CanCanCan—how to stop access to /admin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancancan

I have a rails app using CanCanCan. If I give `manage oauth applications` permisson to a role, then they can access `/oauth/applications/*` which is great.

However, they can also access `/admin/applications`, which I don't want. Is there an easy way to specify that a user needs to be an admin to access `/admin/applications`?

Comment: Are you using active admin ?

Comment: you need to share your relevant parts of the code, like controllers and ability.rb to help us understand your issue